# how can i set ipv6's fragment field when coding my pkts_create's fun?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipv6, scapy

how can i set ipv6's fragment field when coding my pkts_create's fun?

when i use scapy to create my v6's pkts, it doesn's provide a fragment's field  to set, after i searched in it's website, it provide a funtion to set fragment for v6'pkts. i wonder that is there anyway i set fragment when i set it at begining, just like i set src ip.

```
>>> ls(IPv6)
version    : BitField (4 bits)                   = (6)
tc         : BitField (8 bits)                   = (0)
fl         : BitField (20 bits)                  = (0)
plen       : ShortField                          = (None)
nh         : ByteEnumField                       = (59)
hlim       : ByteField                           = (64)
src        : SourceIP6Field                      = (None)
dst        : DestIP6Field                        = (None)
```

and i want to code it like this :

```
pkt=Ether(src, dst)/IPv6(sr, dst, frag=1)/UDP()
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to stack overflow. Please make sure that your question is is written in proper English: it's currently very hard to understand

Comment: The IPv6 header does not have a fragments field the way that IPv4 does. IPv6 is not allowed to fragment along the path the way IPv4 is. IPv6 packets must be pre-fragmented to fit the smallest MTU in the path, which can be discovered with PMTUD. IPv6 fragmentation is very different than IPv4 fragmentation, and it uses Option Headers for that. See _[RFC 8200, Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification Section 4.5. Fragment header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8200#section-4.5)_].

Comment: i'm sorry, my english is poor, i'll try my best to  write it clearly.

Comment: The question is that, when i create ipv6's pkts in scapy, a tool that provide a way to design pkts, IPv6's fragment filed can't be set when i write the functions, but it provide a function to set pkts's  fragment field.

Comment: >>> ls(IPv6)
version    : BitField (4 bits)                   = (6)
tc         : BitField (8 bits)                   = (0)
fl         : BitField (20 bits)                  = (0)
plen       : ShortField                          = (None)
nh         : ByteEnumField                       = (59)
hlim       : ByteField                           = (64)
src        : SourceIP6Field                      = (None)
dst        : DestIP6Field        it doesn's open frag field

Comment: oh , i forget to say thanks, beg your yuanliang!